# How to export a shared_ptr of a fundamental type to python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm trying to use in python a shared_ptr of a fundamental type (for instance int or double), but I don't know how to export it to python:

I have the following class:

```
class Holder
{
public:
    Holder(int v) : value(new int(v)) {};
    boost::shared_ptr<int> value;
};
```

The class is being exported in this way:

```
class_<Holder>("Holder", init<int>())
    .def_readwrite("value", &Holder::value);
```

In the python code, I'm trying to set the "holder instance .value" using an instance that already exists.

```
h1 = mk.Holder(10)
h2 = mk.Holder(20)
h1.value = h2.value
```

The following has occured:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::shared_ptr<int>
```

My question is: how can I export `boost::shared_ptr<int>` to python?

Comment: What kind of semantics do you need? Continuing with your example above, do you expect to be able to assign integer values to `h1.value` and have them reflected in `h2.value`? What about something like this `x = h1.value; x = 42`...should `h2.value` somehow evaluate to `42` after that statement? What you're asking is a bit against the grain in Python, but we can probably find a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) to export `boost::shared_ptr<int>` to Python in the same manner as other types:

```cpp
boost::python::class_<boost::shared_ptr<int> >(...);
```

However, be careful in the semantics introduced when exposing `shared_ptr`.  For example, consider the case where assigning one `Holder.value` to another `Holder.value` simply invokes `boost::shared_ptr<int>`'s assignment operator, and `Holder.increment()` manipulates the `int` pointed to by `value` rather than having `value` point to a new `int`:

```
h1 = Holder(10)
h2 = Holder(20)
h1.value = h2.value # h1.value and h2.value point to the same int.
h1.increment() # Change observed in h2.value.  The semantics may be unexpected
               # by Python developers.
```

---

Here is a complete example exposing `boost::shared_ptr<int>` based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Holder
{
public:
  Holder(int v)
    : value(new int(v))
  {};

  boost::shared_ptr<int> value;
};

std::string holder_value_str(const boost::shared_ptr<int>& value)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << value.get() << " contains " << *value;
  return stream.str();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  {
    python::scope holder = python::class_<Holder>(
        "Holder", python::init<int>())
      .def_readwrite("value", &Holder::value)
      ;

    // Holder.Value
    python::class_<boost::shared_ptr<int> >("Value", python::no_init)
      .def("__str__", &holder_value_str)
      ;
  }
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> h1 = example.Holder(10)
>>> h2 = example.Holder(20)
>>> print h1.value
0x25f4bd0 contains 10
>>> print h2.value
0x253f220 contains 20
>>> h1.value = h2.value
>>> print h1.value
0x253f220 contains 20
```

---

Alternatively, if one considers `shared_ptr` as nothing more than a C++ memory management proxy, then it may be reasonable to expose `Holder.value` as an `int` in Python, even though `Holder::value` is a `boost::shared_ptr<int>`.  This would provide Python developers with the expected semantics and permit statements such `h1.value = h2.value + 5`.  Here is an example that uses auxiliary functions to transform `Holder::value` to and from an `int` instead of exposing the `boost::shared_ptr<int>` type:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Holder
{
public:
  Holder(int v)
    : value(new int(v))
  {};

  boost::shared_ptr<int> value;
};

/// @brief Auxiliary function used to get Holder.value.
int get_holder_value(const Holder& self)
{
  return *(self.value);
}

/// @brief Auxiliary function used to set Holder.value.
void set_holder_value(Holder& self, int value)
{
  *(self.value) = value;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::scope holder = python::class_<Holder>(
      "Holder", python::init<int>())
    .add_property("value",
      python::make_function(&get_holder_value),
      python::make_function(&set_holder_value))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> h1 = example.Holder(10)
>>> h2 = example.Holder(20)
>>> assert(h1.value == 10)
>>> assert(h2.value == 20)
>>> h1.value = h2.value
>>> assert(h1.value == 20)
>>> h1.value += 22
>>> assert(h1.value == 42)
>>> assert(h2.value == 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to?  Python has its own reference counting
mechanism, and it might be simpler just to use that.  (But a lot
depends on what is going on on the C++ side.)

Otherwise: you probably need to define a Python object to
contain the shared pointer.  This is relatively straightforward:
just define something like:

```
struct PythonWrapper
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    boost::shared_ptr<int> value;
    //  Constructors and destructors can go here, to manage
    //  value.
};
```

And declare and manage it like you would any other object; just
make sure you do a `new` when ever objects of the type are
created (and they must be created in functions you provide to
Python, if nothing else in the function in the `tp_new` field),
and a `delete` in the function you put in the `tp_dealloc` field
of the type object you register.